# Can I use the power method to find all eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

With Power Method, I can find the largest eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector. But what if I have and $n,n$ matrix e.g $4,4$

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 3 & 0  \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then I want to compute the eigenvalues.
$$|A - \lambda I| = \begin{vmatrix}
    2 - \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 2- \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 3- \lambda & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 3- \lambda 
  \end{vmatrix} =
  (2 - \lambda)^2(3 - \lambda)^2$$

Here it's easy to find that the eigenvalues are 2 and 3. But with the power method, I would only get number 3. Is a way to re-compute the power method with that eigenvalue 3 and find eigenvalue 2?

Comment: If you've found the largest eigenvalue $3$, then the matrix $3I - A$ has all the same eigenvectors, and eigenvalues equal to $3 - \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$. So, in this case, the power method could be used to identify $1$ as an eigenvalue of $3I - A$, which implies $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Great question -- look up the Arnoldi method.

Comment: As an alternative to @TheoBendit's suggestion, there are algorithms that 'deflate' the matrix to a smaller matrix without the largest eigenvalue. Then the power method can be repeated.